# Optimization of using a speaker membrane as a propulsion unit - best frequency and shape of the excitation curve

Tags: waves, acoustics, propulsion

with optimized frequency and excitation curve pattern, a speaker membrane vibrates with a higher speed away from the speaker (representing frequency 1) and with a lower speed back to the speaker (representing frequence 2), providing trust and an directed net airflow away from the speaker.

So the movement of the speaker membrane is not a sinosoid, rather a **sawtooth** which a sharp rise covering the full range of the amplitude from negative to positive making the speaker membran move **very quickly away** from the speaker and a slow sawtooth part making the membrane move rather slowly back to the speaker, covering for both parts the full range of the amplitude (slope 1 from max. positive to max. negative and then slope 2 from max. negative to max. positive), thereby pushing the air molecules touching the speaker surface with more impulse away from the speaker compared to the returning movement.

Knowing the resonant frequency of the speaker membran setup and its frequency range, is there any rule how to best calculate frequency 1 and 2 (or the parts of the slope of the sawtooth) ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will achieve any net propulsion from such an arrangement. The air that is displaced by the speaker cone outward movement will be replaced during the inward movement, but at a slower rate (due to the slower return velocity of the cone), until the next cycle of the sawtooth wave begins. There can be no net movement of the air, otherwise a constantly increasing pressure differential would be created between the front and back of the speaker cone.

One could postulate a planar valve mechanism in front of the speaker which would prevent the return of air that was pushed through the valve on the outward stroke. This might work to create an constant airflow on the "downwind side" of the planar valve, but if no air could flow from the periphery to the center of the cone on the "upwind side" of the valve, this airflow would inevitably stop.

Comment: I think it is the same principle as in tuk tuk steam boats (a candle creates water vapour which oscillates creating propulsion), which means if there is an asymmetry in the speed of movement of vapour bubbles or a speaker membrane, this will created a directed flow. How else could sound generated by an Iphone blow out a candle? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX6XSs2T5Go

Comment: Note the video doesn't postulate an asymmetry in the speed of the flow, but does postulate directivity (the video calls it coherence) in the outgoing flow and diffuseness in the incoming flow, resulting in the effect.  Also, the video clearly shows a sine wave excitation having the required property.